# Как исключить файлы или каталоги из синхронизации через Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

Например, иногда не имеет смысла синхронизировать какие-то большие файлы, или отдельные каталоги с большим количеством файлов, которые легко восстановить, вроде `node_modules` или `vendor`.

Как можно научить Dropbox игнорировать эти файлы?

Answer (score 3):

С начала 2020 года возможно в самом деле [исключить файлы из процесса синхронизации](https://help.dropbox.com/en-US/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files), а не просто [убрать некоторые каталоги из локальной копии](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/selective-sync-overview), как это можно было делать раньше.

Под Linux и совместимыми пометить файл или каталог как не требующие синхронизации можно этой командой:

```
attr -s com.dropbox.ignored -V 1 /path/to/somewhere
```

Под macOS команда похожая:

```
xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 /path/to/somewhere
```

Под Windows команда следующая:

```
Set-Content -Path C:\Users\yourname\Dropbox\Example -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value 1
```

Также с середины 2019 года Dropbox синхронизирует [символические ссылки как ссылки](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/symlinks), то есть можно перенести что-то, файл или каталог, в другое место выше по иерархии, оставив туда относительную ссылку.

Comment: Прикольно. Но зачем хранить node_modules на dropbox, если есть git с его gitignore? Лично я храню на битбакете не только код, но даже всякий личный хлам.

Comment: Битбакет и Dropbox это весьма разные вещи, простите

Comment: а я просто что нужно сохранить складываю в в папку dropbox и всё ни чего лишнего

Comment: Конечно, это разные вещи, но я не считаю контроль версий и трафика при бэкапе файлов чем-то лишним.